# Android Studio: cannot find "Hello World apps" on emulator screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm new in android development, especially android studio, i try "Hello Word" for my first app, but not found "Hello World app" in my emulator screen. it's look like this:

[image: screen shoot for emulator]

I search these error, but only event log say: `Session 'app': error`. Still didn't get any solution even after a lot of searching. Need help please, for my learning.

Comment: 'app': error -> there's an error when installing app to your emulator.

Comment: @phuc_tran thanks for reply, then how to solve that? sorry i'm newbi

Comment: Restart you emulator and wait for initializing finish. Then try to install again.

Comment: Use `Genymotion` rather using  `AVD`

Comment: I've used `Genymotion`, install it, until i configure `Genimotion` ->settings->tab ADB, I use `custom Android SDK tools` then browse my SDK path->Ok.

@Nilesh I try to run the project, but there is not anything got out from my window. 
I follow the step base on (http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/)

Need advice.